# PDF class not found in dompdf library

Tags: laravel, pdf, download, dompdf

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;
  
class PDFController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function generatePDF()
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'hello world',
            'date' => date('m/d/Y')
        ];
          
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', $data);
    
        return $pdf->download('itsolutionstuff.pdf');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added `PDF` in your facades array??

Comment: no not at the moment but really dont know how to do

Comment: check out the [doc](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). let me know if you still can't understand.

Comment: okay @zahidhasanemon thanks

Comment: Class 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider' not found

Comment: did you install the package using `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`??

Comment: yes @zahidhasanemon   after that in app/config.php  add Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class, and 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,

Comment: check if the package was successfully installed.

Comment: still it shows Error
Class 'PDF' not found

Comment: after installed this package in vendor folder  barryvdh and  in this folder laravel-debugbar , laravel-dompdf sub folder created by default

Comment: can you show me how have you added the service provider and facade in the app config file??

Comment: yes     Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

Comment: 'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
        'Cart' => Darryldecode\Cart\Facades\CartFacade::class,
        'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,

Comment: but still you are getting the error??

Comment: yes still getting this error Class 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider' not found in

Comment: then i afraid the package was not installed successfully. try installing it again.

Comment: okay i try it again ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1:-

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

step-2:-

```
In ..\config\app.php

'providers' => [ 
  Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
]
```

step 3:-

```
use \PDF;
```

Step 4:-

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.file_name');
return $pdf->stream('file_name.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));
```

Step 5:-

```
php artisan cache:clear
// and
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone still looks at this i needed `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` **--dev**

An easy miss i guess..